# how to remove the background for png picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds, png

I would like to make the background transparent. In Texmaker, if I right-click on the TikZ picture, I can save it as a png image as follows

[image]

If I save this picture, I get the white background. Is there a way to remove it?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,arrows.meta, positioning}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=3cm,>={Stealth[width=4mm, length=6mm, fill=red]}]
\coordinate (O) at (5,0);


\draw [very thick,fill=green,fill opacity=.2] 
(-4, 4) circle (2.0cm) node [fill opacity=1]{\textbf{A}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can achieve this within LaTeX, but if you rewrite your question in [Google](https://www.google.com.mx/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=how+to+remove+background+from+a+png+image&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=PxkgVeGNBJewzQL3g4GICA) you can find a lot of tools and trick for achieve it with many options since Paint until Photoshop, IMHO is the easiest way.

Comment: With ImageMagick installed: `convert <file>.pdf <file>.png` will give you a `.png` with transparency.

Comment: The problem is that PDFs are always opaque (simulating paper).  You can use an image editor to make the background transparent, but if you save the result as a PDF, it will be white again.

Comment: @JohnKormylo The PDF produced by the ECM above is not opaque (and does not contain a simulated paper).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is very likely the use of transparency (option `fill opacity`).
The following examples used opaque colors, the lightgreen is achieved by mixing green with white:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [very thick,fill=green!20!white]
  (-4, 4) circle (2.0cm) node {\textbf{A}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This file can be converted to a PNG file, where the background is transparent:

> [image: Result]

The PNG image was converted via ghostscript, full command line of the conversion:

```bash
$ gs -sDEVICE=pngalpha -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 -dUseFastColor=true -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r216x216 -sOutputFile=test.png -ftest.pdf
```