# TikZ standalone picture with semi-transparency converted to png looses transparency

Tags: tikz-pgf, conversion, standalone, transparency

I can successfully create PDF figures using TikZ and convert them with `convert` (ImageMagick) to PNG such that retain a transparent background.
However, with the same procedure, for some of my figures, I instead get a white background. It seems that this happens whenever I have semi-transparent elements in the figure (see [another SE-question, where this conclusion is implicit in the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236815/how-to-remove-the-background-for-png-picture)). This is on Mac OS X. If I use Inkscape, I can get a semi-transparent background, but it typically messes up the fonts (and I don't know how to do it via the CLI).

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue,fill=green,fill opacity=0.1] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` is there because I use a very recent LuaTeX that causes problems with some packages.
Convert with `convert -background transparent test.pdf test.png`.
The result is:

> [image: Result after conversion]

If `fill opacity=0.1` is removed, the result looks as follows:

> [image: Result after conversion, with fill opacity removed]

Comment: As usual, we can do nothing without a MWE to test things on.

Comment: You are right of course, here it is.

Comment: Here, with `convert` version 6.8.9-9, I get the correct result.

Comment: Interesting! My `convert` is version 6.9.7-1. Is it a MacOSX specific thing? Or is `lualatex`the problem (mine is 0.95.0, TeX Live 2016) ?

Comment: I ran it with pdflatex and lualatex (minus the luatex85, which crashed) and converted with Adobe Acrobat and GIMP with no problems.  Gimp offered removing hidden or transparent layers as an option.

Comment: The conversion to png should not be necessary...

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Well, there are use-cases, where such a conversion IS necessary. In my case, it is for a web-based presentation, where strictly speaking, SVG would offer better quality (vector), but performance suffers when there is too much of it.

Comment: @burnpanck `convert` calls `gs` to convert a PDF file to PNG. Here, `gs  --version` gives 9.19 (I use the same `lualatex` version that yours).

Comment: @PaulGaborit That is it! Mine was version 9.10, now with 9.20 it is fixed. If you care to write a full answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`convert` calls `gs` (`ghostscript`) to convert a PDF file to PNG. `gs` version 9.10 seems produce a white background if the PDF file contains semi-transparent objects. A recent version of `gs` (as 9.19 or 9.20) produces the correct result.

> [image]