# How to make transparent background from pdf to png

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency, latex-2-png

I try to convert a latex pdf to png and the background should be transparent.

So I use pdftopng from [XpdfReader](http://www.xpdfreader.com/pdftopng-man.html) for windows to convert: (bat-File)

```
pdflatex Other.tex
pdfcrop Other.pdf
pdftopng -r 300 Other-crop.pdf Other
del Other-crop.pdf
```

The source is:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [very thick,fill=green!20!white]
  (-4, 4) circle (2.0cm) node {\textbf{A}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

from the example [how to remove the background for png picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236815/how-to-remove-the-background-for-png-picture)

with the result:

[image]

Is there a way to convert the pdf to a png with a transparent background using pdftopng?

Answer (score 4):

With ImageMagick instead of `pdftopng` it's simple:

```
convert -density 300 Other-crop.pdf Other.png
```

> [image]

Comment: Do you have an idea what I have to do, that for example the "A" in the circle get transparent too? Is there a way in tikz/latex to print something that interpreted as transparent in png?

Comment: @MarTin If you change the colour of `A` to white (or any other colour that is not the same as the line around the circle), you can use the `-transparent white` option

Comment: thanks you for your advice to imagemagick, I really like the project and I edit my first answer with the imagemagick solution. Have good evening.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution for [pdftopng](http://www.xpdfreader.com/pdftopng-man.html):** (transparent background only)

```
pdflatex Other.tex
pdfcrop Other.pdf
pdftopng -r 300 -alpha Other-crop.pdf Other
del Other-crop.pdf
```

**Prepare for imagemagick:**

1. download [imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)
2. download [ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html)

**Solution for imagemagick:**

define a transparent color in latex:

```
\definecolor{ColorTrans}{RGB}{0, 255, 0}
```

fill elements with it that should be transparent (background excluded)

```
\begin{document} %DOCUMENT BEGIN
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [very thick,fill=green!20!white,text=white,font=\Huge] (-5, 4) circle (1.0cm) node {\textbf{A}};
\draw [very thick,fill=green!20!white,text=ColorTrans,font=\Huge] (-3, 4) circle (1.0cm) node {\textbf{A}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

run bat-file and define the transparent color:

```
pdflatex Other.tex
pdfcrop Other.pdf
magick convert -density 300 -transparent "rgb(0,255,0)" Other-crop.pdf Other.png 
del Other-crop.pdf
```

result:

> [image]